# Is there a way to make a (recursive) make -j invocation go depth first?

Tags: makefile

I have a "typical" recursive `Makefile` building a series of libraries (hundreds of cpp files for each library), and a 8 cores machine.

Now when I run `make -j N` I see that `make` (GNU Make 3.81, for the record) operates in breadth-first, immediately starting ~N recursive calls (as I can see from the output that it's building in parallel files belonging to different libraries).

Just for the sake of the experiment, I've tried to run a manual step of depth-first, by doing a

```
for i in list-of-subdirs-topologically-sorted; do 
    pushd "$i" && make -j N && popd
done
```

To my surprise, this cut almost a minute from the build time on cold caches. I guess there's a better CPU cache usage (and disk usage as well), maybe because inside a library you'll find the same includes included many times, or whatnot...

So, is there a switch to actually get `make` to operate in depth-first?

(Yes, the roadmap would be converting to CMake + ninja in the future...)

Comment: I believe the only way you can influence the order in which `make -j` builds things is to change the order of the prerequisites at the various steps as make defaults to trying to build prerequisites in order and mostly keeps that ordering (I believe) when in `-j` mode.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a switch to actually get make to operate in depth-first?

No. Not as of GNU make 4.2.1 in 2018.

I'm also inclined to believe that depth first search is a concept that applies to searching tree-like data structures with a single cursor. What does it mean to make a depth-first search with N cursors in parallel? Is this well-defined?